# Table not feed using pandas to_sql when this is the last instruction

Tags: mysql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

My issue is that I can select the records loaded into the table "crime_data" ONLY IF I this is not the last table I fed.

- For example, this works (because I create the table essai2_data after the creation of the table crime_data):

```
dfChicagoCrimeData = pd.read_csv('ChicagoCrimeData.csv')
dfChicagoCrimeData.to_sql(con=myConn, name='crime_data', if_exists='replace')

dfChicagoCrimeData.to_sql(con=myConn, name='essai2_data', if_exists='replace')

%sql SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crime_data
```

- This gives me an empty result:

```
dfChicagoCrimeData = pd.read_csv('ChicagoCrimeData.csv')
dfChicagoCrimeData.to_sql(con=myConn, name='crime_data', if_exists='replace')

%sql SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crime_data
```

Can you help me understand why ?

Thanks

R: this is how I configure my connection:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
! pip install PyMySQL
! pip install ipython-sql
! pip install mysqlclient
%load_ext sql
%sql mysql://myUser:myPassword@localhost/chicago_db
myEngine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://myUser:myPassword@localhost/chicago_db")
myConn = myEngine.connect()
```

I tried the instruction %sql COMMIT, but the result was the same